# Why is there formal parameter type in static method Stream.empty() although there is no parameter in the method?

Tags: java-8, generic-type-argument

*Formal parameter type* is allowed in Java **8** and, it is usually used when there are parameters with *generic types* AFAIK.

However, there are indeed some methods without parameters but *formal parameter type* anyway. For instance,

[`<T> Stream<T> java.util.stream.Stream.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#empty--)

Anyone can explain on this?

Comment: it's not different than `Collections.emptyMap()` for example

Comment: “it is usually used when there are parameters with generic types”. Of course, they are also used when there is a generic return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type argument is required here to specify the element type of the returned empty `Stream`. Otherwise this method would return a raw `Stream` type.

For example:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.empty();
```